# C++ regex matching multiple lines

Tags: c++, regex

I'm trying to emulate the work of a simple assembler (as part of my CS course) on the following **input string : "MOV R\nADD R\nSUB 30\nSTORE 1000\nHALT"**

I want to separate the individual instructions from that string. So I used the following **regex pattern**: **"^.+$"**, which means it should match 1 or more characters beginning and ending at new lines.

However, the C++ regex_match function does not get any matches for that pattern. But an online tester showed me that the pattern produces exactly what I need.

Here's my code snippet trying to extract the instructions:

```
regex regInst("^.+$", regex::flag_type::icase | regex::flag_type::ECMAScript);
string input = "MOV R\nADD R\nSUB 30\nSTORE 1000\nHALT";
smatch instructions, opcode, operand;
regex_match(input, instructions, regInst); // *instructions* is empty after this
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2013. I've tried using the following patterns as well:

- ^(.+)$
- (^.+$)+

Comment: Please don't use Regular-Expressions to parse assembly code. Assembly-code is not an example of a Regular-Language, and so cannot be correctly parsed by a Regular-Expression.

Comment: Although you're using regex as a means of splitting a string (and if you're using C/C++, just use `strtok`), this is a bad idea from a memory-consumption perspective. Just use a simple finite-state-machine parser instead (and it will keep your memory-consumption to a minimum as well).

Comment: But the online tester was able to parse it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the anchors `^` and `$` in single-line mode, so `^` only matches the start of a string, and `$` matches the end of a string, rather than anchoring to line-endings.

C++ `regex` library does not have the multi-line/single-line options that .NET Regexes have, so you'll want to use `regex_search` instead of `regex_match`, but as I said in my comment-reply to your original posting: you shouldn't be using regular-expressions to parse assembly code, and using regex as a crude tokenization tool is using pile-driver when all you need is a hammer: `strtok` is your friend.

```
char* input = "MOV R\nADD R\nSUB 30\nSTORE 1000\nHALT";
const char* delimiters = " \n"

char* token = strtok( input, delimiters  );
while( token != nullptr ) {

    cout << token << endl;
    token = strtok( nullptr, delimiters );
}
```

Note that `strtok` is stateful, which explains the non-deterministic nature of subsequent calls to `strtok` with `nullptr` as the first argument. This is documented here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

Also note that `strtok` actually modifies the input string, hence why `input` is `char*` rather than `const char* const` or `string` (because `string::c_str()` returns a `const char*`).

`strtok` is one of the C functions which doesn't have a C++-idiomatic alternative, unfortunately. You could use Boost's `string::split` method but this introduces new memory allocation, whereas `strtok` modifies the string buffer in-place to convert delimiters to `\0` so you can use the `char*` values with null-terminated string functions - so it has its benefits (i.e. no extra memory need be allocated or extra string copying).

---

A more complete solution:

A problem with `strtok` is that you don't know which delimiter was just overwritten, so when you have a grammar which confers different delimiters different semantics (as in your case: '' (a space) is an operand-separator and '`\n' is an opcode separator.

The solution is to have a copy of the string which is not modified, and use the relative-pointers to get the character index to determine what delimiter was encountered. This does somewhat defeat the point of using `strtok` to minimize memory usage though, but it does eliminate the need to test each returned value as a means of enforcing your grammar rules:

```
const char input[] = "MOV R\nADD R\nSUB 30\nSTORE 1000\nHALT";
char* temp = calloc( sizeof(input), sizeof(char) );
strcpy( temp, input );

const char* delimiters = " \n"

char* token = strtok( temp, delimiters  );
while( token != nullptr ) {
    char delimiter = input[ token - temp ];

    cout << token << endl;

    switch( delimiter ) {
        case ' ':
            cout << token << " ";
            break;
        case '\n':
            cout << endl << token << " ";
            break;
    }

    token = strtok( nullptr, delimiters );
}
```

Comment: Ok, but take a look at the documentation on ECMAScript at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ECMAScript/
It says that ^ implies "Either it is the beginning of the target sequence, or follows a line terminator." and $ implies "Either it is the beginning of the target sequence, or follows a line terminator." Line terminators include "\n" so this should have worked.

Anyway I used regex because I thought it would be easier (and that doc misled me), but your solution is clean and simple so thank you :)

Comment: @MrWarlock616 `^` and `$` match newlines only when you're using the `match_flag_type` options. Look at `match_not_bol` and `match_not_eol` (for `^` and `$` respectively).

Comment: Sorry I meant $ implies "Either it is the end of the target sequence, or precedes a line terminator."

Comment: But wouldn't those flags prevent the matching of the start and end of string?

Comment: I'd vote you up but I'm new here